# React useEffect hook triggers only for the last element of the list, what could be the reason for that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am building a UI where if the user scrolls the elements on the page should respond with their custom animations. I have a Parent component in `<Experiment />` and children `<Arcticle />` component. I am using a hook to determine if the user is scrolling *down or up* in each of the children and then I have registered a React hook wherein on scroll I am going to execute animation function (*implementation pending*).

**Parent Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "/styles/Experiment.module.css";
import Article from "../components/Article";

const Experiment = () => {
  const [n] = React.useState(
    Array(3)
      .fill(1)
      .map((n, index) => {
        console.log("mapping");
        return { articleId: n + index, ref: React.createRef() };
      })
  );
  return (
    <div className={styles.experiment}>
      {n.map(({ articleId, ref }, index) => {
        console.log("rendering");
        return <Article key={index} articleId={articleId} articleRef={ref} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Experiment;
```

**Children Component**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./article.module.css";
import { useScrollDirection, useImageToDeviceSize } from "utils/hooks";

const Article = ({ articleId, articleRef, ...props }) => {
  const [canvasWidth, setCanvasWidth] = React.useState(null);
  const { width } = useImageToDeviceSize({
    initHeight: 400,
    initWidth: 400,
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("set canvas", width);
    if (!width) return;
    setCanvasWidth(width);
  }, [width]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cloud", canvasWidth);
    if (!canvasWidth) return;
    cloud(articleId);
  }, [canvasWidth]);
  const { direction } = useScrollDirection();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Article Ref", articleRef);
  }, [articleRef]);

  const drawRect = (id) => {
      const colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
      var c = document.getElementById(id);
      var context = c.getContext("2d");
      context.rect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      context.fillStyle = colors[id - 1];
      context.fill();
  };

  const handleDirection = (direction, articleRef) => {
    switch (direction) {
      case "DOWN": {
        articleRef.current.style.position = "relative";
        articleRef.current.style.left = "0px";
        articleRef.current.style.top = "0px";
        break;
      }
      case "UP": {
        articleRef.current.style.position = "relative";
        articleRef.current.style.left = "-32px";
        articleRef.current.style.top = "-32px";
        break;
      }
      default: {
      }
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!direction) return;
    console.log("article ref scroll", direction, articleRef);
    handleDirection(direction, articleRef);
  }, [direction]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.article} id={`div-${articleId}`} ref={articleRef}>
      {canvasWidth && (
        <canvas width={canvasWidth} height={canvasWidth} id={articleId} />
      )}
      {articleId}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

The problem is that the `handleDirection` method I registered in the React hook only executes for the last child in the list. As the logs I have show in the console, it seems the `articleRef` is getting overridden at some point to store `#div-3` for the last element.

[image]

If someone can point what I am doing wrong or what is the right approach to implement this functionality, that will be really helpful and I will mark their answer correct.

---

[**CodeSandBox Live**](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shadow-et8lyc):

- Scroll up and down inside the browser body to see the effect on last element
- (*updated `createRef` in Experiment to `useRef` in Article*)

Comment: You need to use forwardRef to your child component

Comment: I followed this [link](https://felixgerschau.com/react-forwardref-explained/), it shows how to use one child with useRef (*I am using createRef*). Any suggestion on how to use useRef for multiple children. Aside from that I did change the Article component to forwardRef, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Well for starters - createRef is for class components. You need useRef. Also you can create as many as you want. In anycase my suggestion to forwardRef is not necessary because you aren't actually needing the ref from the parent you might as well create the useRef in the child component

Comment: I quickly updated the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shadow-et8lyc?file=/src/App.js) to remove `createRef` and implement `useRef` in `<Article />`. That also didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` is working only on the last child because of the following reason.

In your custom hook, you are setting scroll listener wrongly - `window.onscroll = () => {...}`. This will override previous scrollHandlers and thus direction is updated only for the component that called this hook last.

To solve this, you can try using `window.addEventListener`. However, you should not create so many event handlers when you can reuse the same state. A better option is to move your direction state to a parent component or a global state.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is a link where I made some edits to debug and do POC - https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wildflower-iq3zmw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Looks good, I will take your suggestion of moving direction as state of parent component then we can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks! your code fixed the issue, I will update my question to incorporate the actual problem